# phpseclib 2.0 can not use Composer to create autoload

Tags: php, phpseclib

I work for a company that has our servers and computer locked down tighter than ... well imagine something really tight. This means I can not use composer or install it without mountains of paperwork. I am a developer, normally programming in JS and not php, but for this project I need to get CAC X509 information off smart cards. I have been at it for about 4 hours now trying to get the phpseclib to work. Mind you, I barely understand php. I am following the directions from github and the website, mainly I have downloaded and unzipped the files for 2.0 and placed them in my directory, I am following the examples from the website such as http://phpseclib.sourceforge.net/x509/2.0/examples.html#getpublickey . but when ever I do:

```
$x509 = new X509();
$x509->loadX509($_SERVER['SSL_CLIENT_CERT']);
echo $x509->getPublicKey();
```

I get the error: 
Fatal error: Class 'X509' not found in ...

I have also tried other things such as including the directory to the file like:

```
$x509 = new phpseclib\File\X509();
$x509->loadX509($_SERVER['SSL_CLIENT_CERT']);
echo $x509->getPublicKey();
```

and (new phpseclib_File_X509) get the error:
Fatal error: Class 'phpseclib\File\X509' not found in ...

Please help! I have never had to do an autoload and I have a feeling this is the issue? Like the files aren't loading? I have also done both below at separate times as well to no avail.

```
include'phpseclib/File/X509.php';

use phpseclib\File\X509;
```

When I put the error log in X509 to check there I get that ASN1 not found as well.

EDIT: Also would help to know that my php version is 5.5.26

Answer (score 2):

You could use the latest 1.0.x version, which doesn't require an autoloader at all (and is still maintained):

http://sourceforge.net/projects/phpseclib/files/phpseclib1.0.18.zip/download

Alternatively, you /can/ use the latest 2.0.x version if you supply your own autoloader. http://phpseclib.sourceforge.net/2.0.html demos this:

```php
<?php
// autoload.php's content can be copy / pasted from https://github.com/composer/composer/blob/master/src/Composer/Autoload/ClassLoader.php
include 'autoload.php';

$loader = new \Composer\Autoload\ClassLoader();
$loader->addPsr4('phpseclib\\', __DIR__ . '/path/to/phpseclib2.0');
$loader->register();

use phpseclib\Crypt\RSA;
use phpseclib\Net\SSH2;

$key = new RSA();
$key->loadKey(file_get_contents('private-key.txt'));

// Domain can be an IP too
$ssh = new SSH2('www.domain.tld');
if (!$ssh->login('username', $key)) {
    exit('Login Failed');
}

echo $ssh->exec('pwd');
echo $ssh->exec('ls -la');
```

This approach lets you use 2.0.x without needing to do composer require phpseclib/phpseclib on the CLI.

Answer (score 0):

You need to follow standard [Composer project setup instructions](https://getcomposer.org/doc/01-basic-usage.md), Larry. After that, you follow instructions on [phpseclib](https://github.com/phpseclib/phpseclib) with Composer by doing

```
composer require phpseclib/phpseclib:~2.0
```

from within root project directory. After that you will not be required to use include/require from examples on the Sourceforge site as those do not use autoload feature of Composer - you follow [this](http://phpseclib.sourceforge.net/2.0.html) example to make use of it.

Comment: Hi, yes, but as I said, I can't install or use composer. That's where I am hitting my issues.

Comment: In that case you won’t be able to do much since version 2.0 uses Composer with PSR-4. You might try going back to previous version, or seek a way to start using Composer - if you have access to console you can download and start using it manually through command “php.exe composer.phar require phpseclib/phpseclib:~2.0“

Answer (score 0):

Any [Composer](https://getcomposer.org/) library can be used as a stand-alone application include, and can be obtained from any computer with Composer installed, then uploaded to another machine.

**Linux shell example:**

```sh
# Navigate to desired download location:
cd /var/www/html/

# Remove prior directory if it exists
sudo rm -rf vendor-downloads 

# Make directory
mkdir -p vendor-downloads

# Navigate into directory
cd vendor-downloads 

# Get the software library via Composer (version 3.0 or 2.0 if desired)
composer require phpseclib/phpseclib:~3.0
```

This will result in a folder structure as follows:

```
/var/www/html/vendor-downloads/
- composer.json
- composer.lock
- vendor/
  -- autoload.php
  -- composer
  -- paragonie
  -- phpseclib
```

The files `composer.json` and `composer.lock` can be ignored. The "vendor" directory can be changed to any other name if desired. In this example, say it's changed to the application name, "phpseclib" for clarity.

```
- phpseclib/
  -- autoload.php
  -- composer
  -- paragonie
  -- phpseclib
```

**In any PHP application, use the Composer downloaded library as a stand-alone include as follows:**

```php
<?php

    include_once('/path/to/phpseclib/autoload.php');
    
    // Test
    
    use phpseclib3\Net\SSH2;

    $ssh = new SSH2('localhost', 22);
    echo '<pre>'.print_r($ssh,true).'</pre>';  

?>
```